# Unknown custom element: <v-calendar>

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to use Vuetify's calendar feature. I can compile everything but this is what I get when I try to render:
Unknown custom element v-calendar - did you register the component correctly?

```
<template>
    <v-card style="margin:20px;">
        <v-calendar
            type="week"
            now="2019-01-08"
            value="2019-01-08"
            :events="events"
        ></v-calendar>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import moment from 'moment'
    import API from '@/mixins/API.js'
    import router from '@/router'
    import Vuetify, {VCalendar} from 'vuetify'
    import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
        VCalendar
    });
    //some more code
</script>
```

Comment: which vuetify version are you using? 1.5 or 2?

Comment: The way the code is written in the question makes it look like you're importing Vuetify directly into a SFC. Could you confirm that this is not the case and that you're actually doing this in `main.js` or similar, the same file in which you call `new Vue`?

Comment: I had the code in one of my "Calendar" components but I already have "import Vuetify from 'vuetify'" in my main.js file. I didn't think it mattered if I tried to import the VCalendar from my "Calendar" component.

Comment: Also, I'm running Vue 2.9.6

Comment: You should remove the Vuetify `import`/`use` code from your calendar component. We would need to see the relevant code from `main.js` to figure out what the problem is. Please could you let us know what version of Vuetify you are using? Vue 2.9.6 doesn't exist, I assume that's the Vue CLI version.

Comment: It says that the version of vuetify is 0.17.7 I'm going to install the latest one

Answer (score 1):

You may not be loading the vuetify components properly. Try adding the following code to your template:

```
<script>
import { VCalendar } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
    components: { VCalendar },
    ...
}
</script>
```

If you don't want to load components manually every time you can also [check out the vuetify-loader plugin](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader) which will automatically add components for you.